# if statement in CSS on Shopify is not working

Tags: css, shopify, flexslider, liquid

I am trying to add a caption to a flexslider on Shopify.
This is my code on theme.liquid

```
          {% for i in (1..10) %}
          {% capture display_slideshow %}display_slideshow_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
          {% capture slide %}slideshow_{{ i }}.jpg{% endcapture %}
          {% capture link %}image_{{ i }}_link{% endcapture %}
          {% capture alt %}image_{{ i }}_alt{% endcapture %}
          {% capture caption %}image_{{ i }}_caption{% endcapture %} {% comment %} <-- I am adding this one {% endcomment %}

          {% if settings[display_slideshow] %}
             <li class="slide">
                    <img src="{{ slide | asset_url }}" data-url="{{ settings[link] }}" class="slide-img" alt="{{ settings[alt] }}" />  
             <p class="flex-caption">{{ settings[caption] }}</p>  {% comment %} <-- I am adding this one {% endcomment %}
          </li>
          {% endif %} 
      {% endfor %}
```

My shop.css.liquid

I am adding

```
{% if settings.caption %}

.flex-caption
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:20px;
    z-index:1;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0,0.6); 
    padding:20px 0 10px 10px;
    height:33px;
    width:500px;
    color:#FFF;
}

{% endif %}
```

It is still showing the background even when a caption is not applied.

Comment: is `settings.caption` a global setting (for example: enable caption on all slides) or should it be a slide specific setting?

Comment: No, it is not a global setting. How can I set as a global? I am very new to Shopify

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add a caption textbox for each slides then check if settings.caption != "" (not empty string).

It may be an easier option to simply not output the caption element for slides that has none rather than messing with the css class.

Read more here http://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-templates/settings#settings-object-in-liquid

Hope this helps.